# mysql join multiple queries

Tags: mysql, join

I have two sql queries on one table. Both the queries working independently fine with desired results. I want to use join the queries to have the results. Some how in mysql workbench it is showing error near JOIN statement. Can some one help?

```
select a.eod_symbol, a.eod_date, a.eod_close,
    round(avg(a.eod_close) over w, 2) as sma5
    from t_eoddata as a
    where a.eod_date <='2017-01-11' and a.eod_symbol='XXX'
    window w as (order by a.eod_date asc rows 4 PRECEDING)
    ORDER BY a.eod_symbol asc, a.eod_date asc

JOIN

-- calculate 10 day simple moving average
(select eod_symbol, eod_date, eod_close,
    round(avg(eod_close) over w, 2) as sma10
    from t_eoddata
    where eod_date <='2017-01-11' and eod_symbol='XXX'
    window w as (order by eod_date asc rows 9 PRECEDING)
    ORDER BY eod_symbol asc, eod_date asc) as b
    on (a.eod_symbol=b.eod_symbol and a.eod_date=b.eod_date);
```

Comment: you might need to wrap the first query in `()`

Comment: .. and give an alias `a` to it. PS. You may remove ORDER BY from both queries - it will be ignored anycase. But you may to add ORDER BY to the combined query.

Comment: Are you sure you need `JOIN` looks as `UNION ALL` case

Comment: I need the output rows to contain eod_symbol, eod_date, eod_close, sma5, sma10
where sma5 is output from first query and sma10 is output from second query. I think it can be achieved by using JOIN properly but not UNION.